# Failed attempt to refinance my rental property, can I deduct the cost of appraisal?

Tags: united-states, taxes, rental-property

I attempted to refinance my rental property in 2012, but the appraisal came in low making it impossible. Can I consider the cost of the appraisal and rent schedule (close to $600) to be a rental expense?

Comment: I'm making a wild guess here that you're from the US, right?

Comment: Yes, I am in Texas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can, under professional fees. To be sure, you should ask a professional tax preparer or tax adviser (CPA/EA).